# Who will represent the party in the EU parliament after it won some seats?

Tags: united-kingdom, election, european-parliament

Let's say party A has won 3 seats out of 10 seats in South East Region of UK in the recent European Parliament election.

How does that party choose 3 out of its initial 10 MEP candidates whose name are shown on the voting ballot paper?

Comment: If I'm not mistaking the lists in the UK are ranked, and in contrast with what happens in some other countries you cannot change the list when voting, so you end up with the top 3 candidates.

Comment: Not sure about the UK, but where I live once the party computes the list, it is static (the order does not change). That is why for a candidate the place on that list is crucial ("eligible places" = places that are plausible to materialize in seats for that party). I think the same system is in place for local parliament elections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EU party lists are ranked. So when the party earned 3 seats, the top 3 people on their list become MEPs.

The list ranking order is determined by the party through an internal process.

Comment: The order was shown on the ballot paper

Comment: Just to clarify, does each region (in the UK) have its own list of candidates with its own ranking?

Comment: @JJJ - yes. A different list in each voting region